# unable to install Gulp on nodejs

Tags: node.js, windows, proxy, gulp, firewall

I am getting the below error while i run the command "npm install gulp -g".

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "gulp" "-g"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT (IP)
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MID\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: No, I have disabled proxy.